# How to manually set up tumblr theme, so link will open in new tab?

Tags: html, tumblr

I have a Tumblr blog (http://tivonim.tumblr.com), and I want links to open in a new window. On the setting page this option is checked but it's still opening links in the same window. I want the people who click on the images will not leave my site. So, if the regular settings doesn't work, I think I may as well do it manually on the theme code myself. Problem is, as much as I try to add the "target:_blank" code on the code, it doesn't work. I be pasting it on the wrong place.
I would also like the post credit to open in a new window. I tried to do it with the theme code, by adding the "target:_blank":

```
<div class="post_credit">
    למתכון המלא: {block:SourceLogo}<a href="{SourceURL}" target="_blank"><img src="{BlackLogoURL}" width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" /></a>{/block:SourceLogo}
    {block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo}
</div>
```

However, it still opens those links in the same window.

I heard it happens to other people, but none of them know how to work this out.

Comment: You need ot close the href attribute of the a tag, such that: <a href="{SourceURL}" target="_blank">

Comment: You right, but even after doing this - the link is still opens in the same tab. 
(I edited the code on the question, so the href attribute is closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo}` is your problem in that block. This makes a link without the target attribute.

As per the block code from the [Tumblr Guide](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#content-sources) this is what you're wanting:

```
{block:ContentSource}
<div class="post_credit">
    <a href="{SourceURL}" target="_blank">
        {lang:Source}:
        {block:SourceLogo}
            <img src="{BlackLogoURL}" width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
        {/block:SourceLogo}
        {block:NoSourceLogo}
            {SourceTitle}
        {/block:NoSourceLogo}
    </a>
</div>
{/block:ContentSource}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ally! That works great. But I still have the problem with people clicking on the images and it navigates them outside of my blog in the same window. Reading their guide didn't help me with that.
This is my code:

<div class="thumbnail">
{block:IfUseLightboxForFullSizeImages}
<div class="overlay">
<span>
{LinkOpenTag}<div class="thumbnail_link">{lang:Link}</div>{LinkCloseTag}
{block:IndexPage}<a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="thumbnail_lightbox">{lang:Click for high-res photo}</a>{/block:IndexPage}

Do you have any idea why it still navigates out?

Comment: `<div class="thumbnail"> {block:IfUseLightboxForFullSizeImages} <div class="overlay"> <span> {block:LinkURL}<a href="{LinkURL}" target="_blank"><div class="thumbnail_link">{lang:Link}</div></a>{/block:LinkURL}</span></div>{/block:IfUseLightboxForFullSizeImages} {block:IndexPage}<a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="thumbnail_lightbox">{lang:Click for high-res photo}</a>{/block:IndexPage}</div>` I believe is what you're wanting? I closed some tags that weren't closed and changed the way the `LinkURL` is used.